# Jersey containerRequestFilter for different api versions

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Am creating an API , for that am using Jersey . And i have an authentication mechanism which is invoked in containerRequestFilter class. Everything works fine up to that..
Now am versioning the API, and succeeded in versioning all the resource but in the case of requestfilter am not sure how it works..Am using annotations for versioning

example , for signin resource the url will be `/v1/signin` and `/v2/signin`
which is mentioned using java annotation like `@Path("v1/login")` above resource class name..

How i can version my request filter in this style

please help..am really new to this

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Jersey 2.x, you can use [Dynamic Binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9955), with a little reflection to check the value in the `@Path` annotation. Something like

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.container.DynamicFeature;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class Version1Feature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        Path classAnnotation = resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
        if (classAnnotation != null) {
            String pathValue = classAnnotation.value();
            if (pathValue != null) {
                if (pathValue.contains("v1")) {
                    context.register(Version1Filter.class);
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This will check the `@Path("v1/login")` for every resource class. Each class annotation that contains `"v1"`, it will dynamically register the `Version1Filter` for that class. You can also check at the method level, using `resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Path.class)`. The `configure` method is called for each resource methods you have.

A different feature should be created for each version. You could alternatively use the same feature for all the versions, like

```
@Provider
public class VersioningFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        Path classAnnotation = resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
        if (classAnnotation != null) {
            String pathValue = classAnnotation.value();
            if (pathValue != null) {
                if (pathValue.contains("v1")) {
                    context.register(Version1Filter.class);
                } else if (pathValue.contains("v2")) {
                    context.register(Version2Filter.class);
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

But to me, it makes more sense to implement a different feature for each version, as you won't need to touch the feature implementation while new versions are created.

With Jersey 1.x, it's not as elegant. You'll need to do the checking explicitly in the filter. Something like

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class Version1Filter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest cr, ContainerResponse cr1) {
        String pathValue = cr.getPath();
        if (pathValue.contains("v1")) {
            cr1.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("X-Header", "Version 1.0");
        }
        return cr1;
    }
}
```

You could do the same with Jersey 2, but personally, I think the feature is more elegant.